# Run a custom task asynchronously in airflow using existing celery

Tags: python, redis, airflow, celery

I have a running airflow with celery and redis.
This by default sends dag's task to celery worker.
I want to run a custom task from one of DAG's task from python code.

In tasks.py I have following code.

```
from airflow.configuration import conf
from airflow.config_templates.default_celery import DEFAULT_CELERY_CONFIG
from celery import Celery
from celery import shared_task



if conf.has_option('celery', 'celery_config_options'):
    celery_configuration = conf.getimport('celery', 'celery_config_options')
else:
    celery_configuration = DEFAULT_CELERY_CONFIG

app = Celery(conf.get('celery', 'CELERY_APP_NAME'), config_source=celery_configuration,include=["dags.tasks"])
app.autodiscover_tasks(force=True)
print("here")
print(conf.get('celery', 'CELERY_APP_NAME'))
print(celery_configuration)
print(app)
@app.task(name='maximum')
def maximum(x=10, y=11):
    #print("here")
    print(x)
    if x > y:
        return x
    else:
        return y

tasks = app.tasks.keys()
print(tasks)
```

I am calling this from one of the DAG's task.

```
    max=maximum.apply_async(kwargs={'x':5, 'y':4})
    print(max)
    print(max.get(timeout=5))
```

I am geting

```
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/celery/result.py", line 336, in maybe_throw
    self.throw(value, self._to_remote_traceback(tb))
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/celery/result.py", line 329, in throw
    self.on_ready.throw(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/vine/promises.py", line 234, in throw
    reraise(type(exc), exc, tb)
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/vine/utils.py", line 30, in reraise
    raise value
celery.exceptions.NotRegistered: 'maximum'
```

In the registered tasks from above I am getting :

```
tasks = app.tasks.keys()
print(tasks)
```

output

```
dict_keys(['celery.chunks', 'airflow.executors.celery_executor.execute_command', 'maximum', 'celery.backend_cleanup', 'celery.chord_unlock', 'celery.group', 'celery.map', 'celery.accumulate', 'celery.chain', 'celery.starmap', 'celery.chord'])
```

Maximum is there in registered tasks.

The airflow worker is run from docker as follows(snip from docker-compose.yaml):

```
airflow-worker:
    <<: *airflow-common
    command: celery worker
    healthcheck:
      test:
        - "CMD-SHELL"
        - 'celery --app airflow.executors.celery_executor.app inspect ping -d "celery@$${HOSTNAME}"'
      interval: 10s
      timeout: 10s
      retries: 5
    restart: always
```

Full docker-compose.yaml

```
version: '3'
x-airflow-common:
  &airflow-common
  image: ${AIRFLOW_IMAGE_NAME:-tanesca-airflow:2.1.0}
  environment:
    &airflow-common-env
    AIRFLOW__CORE__EXECUTOR: CeleryExecutor
    AIRFLOW__CORE__SQL_ALCHEMY_CONN: postgresql+psycopg2://airflow:airflow@postgres/airflow
    AIRFLOW__DATABASE__SQL_ALCHEMY_CONN: postgresql+psycopg2://airflow:airflow@postgres/airflow  
    AIRFLOW__CELERY__RESULT_BACKEND: db+postgresql://airflow:airflow@postgres/airflow
    AIRFLOW__CELERY__BROKER_URL: redis://:@redis:6379/0
    AIRFLOW__CORE__FERNET_KEY: ''
    AIRFLOW__CORE__DAGS_ARE_PAUSED_AT_CREATION: 'true'
    AIRFLOW__CORE__LOAD_EXAMPLES: 'false'
    AIRFLOW__API__AUTH_BACKENDS: 'airflow.api.auth.backend.basic_auth'
#    _PIP_ADDITIONAL_REQUIREMENTS: ${_PIP_ADDITIONAL_REQUIREMENTS:-pandas kiteconnect}
#    _PIP_ADDITIONAL_REQUIREMENTS: ${_PIP_ADDITIONAL_REQUIREMENTS:-pandas}
  volumes:
    - ./dags:/opt/airflow/dags
    - ./logs:/opt/airflow/logs
    - ./plugins:/opt/airflow/plugins
  user: "${AIRFLOW_UID:-50000}:${AIRFLOW_GID:-50000}"
#  user: "${AIRFLOW_UID:-50000}:0"
  depends_on:
    redis:
      condition: service_healthy
    postgres:
      condition: service_healthy

services:
  postgres:
    image: postgres:13
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: ****
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: ***
      POSTGRES_DB: ***
    volumes:
      - postgres-db-volume:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    ports:
      - 5432:5432
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD", "pg_isready", "-U", "airflow"]
      interval: 5s
      retries: 5
    restart: always

  redis:
    image: redis:latest
    ports:
      - 6379:6379
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD", "redis-cli", "ping"]
      interval: 5s
      timeout: 30s
      retries: 50
    restart: always

  airflow-webserver:
    <<: *airflow-common
    command: webserver
    ports:
      - 8080:8080
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD", "curl", "--fail", "http://localhost:8080/health"]
      interval: 10s
      timeout: 10s
      retries: 5
    restart: always

  airflow-scheduler:
    <<: *airflow-common
    command: scheduler
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD-SHELL", 'airflow jobs check --job-type SchedulerJob --hostname "$${HOSTNAME}"']
      interval: 10s
      timeout: 10s
      retries: 5
    restart: always

  airflow-worker:
    <<: *airflow-common
    command: celery worker
    healthcheck:
      test:
        - "CMD-SHELL"
        - 'celery --app airflow.executors.celery_executor.app inspect ping -d "celery@$${HOSTNAME}"'
      interval: 10s
      timeout: 10s
      retries: 5
    restart: always

  airflow-init:
    <<: *airflow-common
    command: version
    environment:
      <<: *airflow-common-env
      _AIRFLOW_DB_UPGRADE: 'true'
      _AIRFLOW_WWW_USER_CREATE: 'true'
      _AIRFLOW_WWW_USER_USERNAME: ${_AIRFLOW_WWW_USER_USERNAME:-airflow}
      _AIRFLOW_WWW_USER_PASSWORD: ${_AIRFLOW_WWW_USER_PASSWORD:-airflow}

  flower:
    <<: *airflow-common
    command: celery flower
    ports:
      - 5555:5555
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD", "curl", "--fail", "http://localhost:5555/"]
      interval: 10s
      timeout: 10s
      retries: 5
    restart: always

volumes:
  postgres-db-volume:
```

airflow worker logs

```
 -------------- celery@eecdca8a08ff v5.2.7 (dawn-chorus)
--- ***** ----- 
-- ******* ---- Linux-5.15.0-1019-aws-x86_64-with-debian-11.4 2022-09-02 12:35:42
- *** --- * --- 
- ** ---------- [config]
- ** ---------- .> app:         airflow.executors.celery_executor:0x7fa27b38b0d0
- ** ---------- .> transport:   redis://redis:6379/0
- ** ---------- .> results:     postgresql://airflow:**@postgres/airflow
- *** --- * --- .> concurrency: 16 (prefork)
-- ******* ---- .> task events: OFF (enable -E to monitor tasks in this worker)
--- ***** ----- 
 -------------- [queues]
                .> default          exchange=default(direct) key=default
                

[tasks]
  . airflow.executors.celery_executor.execute_command

[2022-09-02 12:35:50,295: INFO/MainProcess] Connected to redis://redis:6379/0
[2022-09-02 12:35:50,310: INFO/MainProcess] mingle: searching for neighbors
```

Comment: Can you add the command that you are using for running the worker?

Comment: Edited the question with the answer of above comment.

Comment: I think you should pass the app with -A flag (if the worker command)

Comment: Checkout my answer here, might be the same issue https://stackoverflow.com/a/73560931/1011253

Comment: This worker is managed by airflow. I don't know how to add an external celery_app.py to airflow. If I could import tasks.py mentioned in the question to celery that would be great.

Comment: all you want is to run a python code from Airflow's task?

Comment: I want to run custom task which is registered in celery tasks from airflow. Currently when celery is up there is only task (airflow.executors.celery_executor.execute_command) registered by airflow . I want to register one more task or many such tasks and execute them from celery asynchronously

Comment: Gotcha. Can I ask what's the motivation for doing that?

Comment: I have a websocket connection setup which fetches tick by tick data from a broker api. For processing the tick by tick data there are two ways , one is in which threads are spawned and processing is done in those threads, other is passing the ticks to some queue and doing processing there. First one is cpu intensive . Want to implement the queue one. More details are in this thread https://kite.trade/forum/discussion/comment/25535/#Comment_25535

Comment: That's what we are doing in my example. We have a task that run async in celery + airflow. Now I'm confused, why do you need Airflow then?

Comment: airflow is to schedule the jobs which connect to broker and to do things.

Comment: Airflow makes the scheduling easy rather than scheduling from crontab . I thought when we already have a setup of celery, redis and postgres with airflow , maybe there is a way to register some other  custom tasks and run them from airflow PythonOperator tasks.

Comment: Aren't you mixing between celery tasks and Airflow tasks? (Python Operator). The idea of using Celery in Airflow is just for having executors (Celery workers in that case) to run your async tasks (Python Operators). It could have been any other executor as well (Kubernetes for example). You, as an airflow user, are guest in celery workers to run your Airflow tasks.. If

Comment: If you want to use celery tasks you can use only celery + beat without Airflow overhead

Comment: Then I would have to create whole setup again in plain python. Currently I have a system which calls various broker api's to login , execute ,send reports etc in airflow. I will have to do this again with celery + beat or maybe I can drop the celery from the airflow and use the simple celery + beat setup and call from PythonOperator tasks.

Comment: `max` is a built in function btw - so you are overwriting it by making it a variable name! You can replace your maximum function with `return max([x, y])`

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you simply want to run custom Python code within your task. Not sure why you are using Celery decorator, maybe I missed something.

Anyway, I would recommend using `PythonOperator` for that. You need to implement your own logic and it will run in celery worker.

Based on your code above, I've created a short example:

```
import logging
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

from airflow import DAG
from airflow.operators.python import PythonOperator

def maximum(**kwargs):
    logging.warning(f"got this args: {kwargs}")
    x = kwargs.get("x")
    y = kwargs.get("y")
    if x > y:
        return x
    else:
        return y

def minimum(**kwargs):
    logging.warning(f"got this args: {kwargs}")
    x = kwargs.get("x")
    y = kwargs.get("y")
    if x > y:
        return x
    else:
        return y

with DAG(
    'tutorial',
    default_args={
    },
    description='A simple tutorial DAG',
    schedule_interval=timedelta(days=1),
    start_date=datetime(2021, 1, 1),
    catchup=False,
    tags=['example'],
) as dag:
    op_kwargs = {
        "x": 10,
        "y": 11,
    }

    t1 = PythonOperator(
        task_id="my_max_python_task",
        python_callable=maximum,
        dag=dag,
        op_kwargs=op_kwargs
    )

    t2 = PythonOperator(
        task_id="my_min_python_task",
        python_callable=minimum,
        dag=dag,
        op_kwargs=op_kwargs
    )

    t1 >> t2
```

You can see that it ran:
[image]

And return the result (if you have downstream task to consume that):
[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer . But let's assume I have a maximum task which I want to run from this PythonOperator asynchronously. Currently when worker is up airflow registers airflow.executors.celery_executor.execute_command only. I need many more tasks registered , on which I can call delay method and then get them asynchronously. Added airflow worker startup logs in question.

Comment: You don't have to call `delay` explicitly. Airflow does it for you. You don't have to take care of registering other tasks. They will run asynchronously in Celery worker, wrapped by the same `execute_command` but it is transparent for you. You can add a `minimum` function within a 2nd `PythonOperator` and see how it works

Comment: I have added a `minimum` to demonstrate. To increase parallelism you can always add more workers (assuming those will run from multiple DAGs simultaneously).

Comment: Are you still interested in the celery task solution? (mixing those two)

Comment: How can I call minimum from maximum task and then get the result of minimum in maximum task?

Comment: In Celery (without Airflow) - it's a bad practice to call to a celery_task within another celery_task. It may lead to deadlocks and other bad things. In Airflow you can pass results between tasks within DAG by `xcom`. In the example above `maximum` comes before `minimum` so you can pull the return value of `maximum` in the `minimum` task: `task_instance.xcom_pull(task_ids= my_max_python_task)`

Comment: @atul.mishra anything else before losing your bounty? :)