# celery on a separate container

Tags: python, docker, flask, celery

I am attempting to run celery on it's own container from my Flask app.  Right now I am just setting up a simple email app.  The container CMD is

> "["celery", "worker", "--loglevel=info"]"

The message gets sent to the redis broker and celery picks it up, but celery gives me the error.

> "Received unregistered task of type
> 'flask_project.views.send_async_email'. The message has been ignored
> and discarded."

I am setting the include in the celery config on my flask app.  I have restarted and rebuilt my containers and still the same issue.

```
from flask import Blueprint, current_app
from flask_mail import Mail
from os import getenv
from celery import Celery

from .support_func import decorator_require_api

views = Blueprint('views', __name__)

celery = Celery(views.name,
                broker='redis://redis:6379/0',
                include=["views.tasks"])

@celery.task
def send_async_email(email_data):
    mail = Mail()
    mail.send(email_data)

@views.route('/')
def home():
    with current_app.app_context():

        email_data = {'sender': getenv('MAIL_USERNAME'), 'recipients': ['mrjoli021@gmail.com'],
                      'message': "This is a test email"}

        send_async_email.delay(email_data)
    return "Message sent!"
```

Compose:

```
---
version: "3.9"
services:
  flask:
    build:
      context: ./Docker/flask
    container_name: flask
    volumes:
      - ./app/:/app
    restart: unless-stopped
    stdin_open: true
    #entrypoint: /bin/bash
    networks:
      - api
      
  nginx:
    image: nginx:latest
    container_name: nginx
    depends_on:
      - flask
    #entrypoint: /bin/bash
    volumes:
      - ./nginx_config:/etc/nginx/conf.d
      - ./app/:/app
    ports:
      - "5000:443"
    networks:
      - api

  celery:
    build:
      context: ./Docker/celery
    container_name: celery
    depends_on:
      - redis
    restart: unless-stopped
    stdin_open: true
    networks:
      - api

  redis:
    image: redis:latest
    container_name: redis
    depends_on:
      - flask
    #entrypoint: /bin/bash
    networks:
      - api

networks:
  api:
    driver: bridge

  -----------------
DockerFile:

FROM python:3.9.7-slim-buster

WORKDIR /app

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
    build-essential # python-dev libssl-dev openssl

COPY ./ .

RUN pip3 install -r requirements.txt

ENV CELERY_BROKER_URL=redis://redis:6379/0

CMD ["celery", "worker", "--loglevel=info"]
```

Comment: Is your celery service using the redis which is up on port 6379 in your system? if you run them with a docker-compose please provide that with your Dockerfile here this information is not enough.

Comment: Added compose and DockerFile.  YES, I see the tasks hitting redis and celery is getting them from there.  I am looking at the celery logs in the container, and it keeps complaining with the error message above.

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass the celery app to the worker with `--app` or `-A` flag (see my answer/example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45908901/1011253)).

I would recommend to refactor a bit and extract this snippet:

```
celery = Celery(views.name,
                broker='redis://redis:6379/0',
                include=["views.tasks"])
```

to external file, such as `celery_app.py` and then import it for your flask app and use it for the worker:

```
["celery", "--app", "your_module.celery_app:celery", "worker", "--loglevel=info"]
```

You should see the registered tasks within the worker's startup logs (when you see the big C (Celery) logo..

Comment: when I use the --app or -A option, I keep getting "Error: No such option: -A"  I am using:```celery worker -A flask_project.celery_app:celery```

Comment: My bad, this flag should come before the `worker`: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67145004/the-support-for-this-usage-was-removed-in-celery-5-0-instead-you-should-use-a/67146291#67146291 (will edit my answer)

Comment: @user2236794 did it answer your question? :)

Answer (score 1):

I finally figured it out.  I used https://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/celery-and-the-flask-application-factory-pattern
as a reference.  Now I can register new blueprints without touching the celery config.  It is a work in progress, but now the containers are all up and running.

```
.
├── Docker
│   ├── celery
│   │   ├── Dockerfile
│   │   └── requirements.txt
│   └── flask
│       ├── Dockerfile
│       └── requirements.txt
├── app
│   ├── flask_project
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   ├── celery_app.py
│   │   └── views.py
├── docker-compose.yml



Compose:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
---
version: "3.9"
services:
  flask:
    build:
      context: ./Docker/flask
    container_name: flask
    volumes:
      - ./app/:/app
    restart: unless-stopped
    stdin_open: true
    networks:
      - api

  nginx:
    image: nginx:latest
    container_name: nginx
    depends_on:
      - flask
    #entrypoint: /bin/bash
    volumes:
      - ./nginx_config:/etc/nginx/conf.d
      - ./app/:/app
    ports:
      - "5000:443"
    networks:
      - api

  celery:
    build:
      context: ./Docker/celery
    container_name: celery
    depends_on:
      - redis
    volumes:
      - ./app/:/app
    restart: unless-stopped
    stdin_open: true
    networks:
      - api

  redis:
    image: redis:latest
    container_name: redis
    depends_on:
      - flask
    #entrypoint: /bin/bash
    networks:
      - api

networks:
  api:
    driver: bridge

celery_app.py:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
from . import celery, create_app

app = create_app()
app.app_context().push()


__init__.py:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
from celery import Celery

celery = Celery(__name__, broker=getenv('CELERY_BROKER_URL'))


def create_app():
    app = Flask(__name__)

    # Celery stuff
    celery.conf.update(app.config)


    # Register Blueprints
    from .views import views

    app.register_blueprint(views, url_prefix='/')

    return app

views.py:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

from flask import Blueprint, current_app
from flask_mail import Message, Mail
from os import getenv
from . import celery

views = Blueprint('views', __name__)


@celery.task
def send_async_email(email_data):
    msg = Message(email_data['subject'],
                  sender=email_data['sender'],
                  recipients=email_data['recipients'],
                  )
    msg.body = email_data['message']
    mail = Mail()
    mail.send(msg)

@views.route('/')
def home():

    with current_app.app_context():
        email_data = {'sender': getenv('MAIL_USERNAME'),
                      'recipients': ['some_email@gmail.com'],
                      'subject': 'testing123',
                      'message': "testing123"
                      }

        msg = Message(email_data['subject'],
                      sender=email_data['sender'],
                      recipients=email_data['recipients'],
                      )
        msg.body = email_data['message']

        send_async_email.delay(email_data)
    return "Message sent!"
```